# Spring MVC Java-based configuration can't see class-path properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-mvc-test

I'm trying to migrate my web-app from XML-based configuration to Java-based one. I have properties files under "\src\main\resources\" directory. In XML configuration I had such bean:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And it worked just fine.

Now I switched to Java config so I have:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"blah.blah.blah.*"})
@Import({MVCConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class TestConfig {


}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:155)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:WEB-INF/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
...
```

I've tried to use @PropertySource("classpath*:test.properties"), then exception changes to:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to load bean class: blah.blah.blah.TestConfig; nested
>   exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [classpath*:test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist ...

Leading slash also doesn't help...

My test class starts as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class IntegrationTests {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try making it `classpath:/test.properties`.

Comment: The error says that the actual path you're using is classpath:WEB-INF/test.properties, not classpath:test.properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad: I also had `@Bean` of type `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and it conflicted somehow with `@PropertySource` annotation. Removing this been fixed things up.

Comment: Note that `/WEB-INF` is not typically added to the classpath.